# Bootstrap 3.1.0: affix too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using *Bootstrap 3.1.0*. When an "affix" gets too long for the viewport, it gets cut off, never showing bottom items.

Is there a possibility to have Bootstrap's affix behave in a way that it is still possible for the user to scroll the complete affix from top to bottom?

Problematic example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="list-group" id="sidebar">
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Long</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">list</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">with</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">many</a>
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">entries</a>
                ...
                <a href="#" class="list-group-item">29. Last</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
          ... regular content    
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

[I hope my jsFiddle exemplifies this problem](http://jsfiddle.net/Abdull/Ja3XT/).

Comment: I don't know your particular use-case, but is it entirely necessary to actually have that many items in an affix that it's larger than a viewport? In your example, if I were to load the page with a smaller width viewport, then I have to scroll through that many elements because the sidebar gets loaded at the top of the page.

I feel you would have much better results and user experience if you had expandable sections, and tried to minimize the size of the sidebar.

Answer (score 8):

I hope it can help you :

Just add an `overflow-y`

**Jsfiddle :** http://jsfiddle.net/Ja3XT/1/

**Added Css :**

```
#sidebar{
 max-height: 100%;
 overflow-y: auto;   
}
```

**UPDATE AFTER COMMENT:**

***fiddle :***   http://jsfiddle.net/F4FZL/1/

**JS :**

```
$('#sidebar').affix({
    offset: {
        top:100,
        bottom:0
    }
});


$('#sidebar').on('affixed.bs.affix', function(){
    $(this).removeAttr('style');
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this already points me into a good direction. Though I noticed that your solution at http://jsfiddle.net/Ja3XT/1/ may run into usability problems when the *content part* gets shorter than the *affix part*. Here is the jsFiddle exemplifing this problem (problematic at least in Chrome 33 and IE 11): http://jsfiddle.net/Abdull/F4FZL/ . When scrolling down, the window jerks around and jumps back to the upper part, never revealing the bottom affix parts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I spent a few hours and finnaly I wrote the following solution:

```
$('#sidebar').on('affix.bs.affix', function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        affix = $this.data('bs.affix'),
        offset = affix.options.offset,
        offsetBottom = offset.bottom;

    if (typeof offset != 'object') {
        offsetBottom = offset;
    }

    if (typeof offsetBottom == 'function') {
        offsetBottom = offset.bottom($this);
    }

    if ($this.outerHeight() + $this.offset().top + offsetBottom === Math.max($(document).height(), $(document.body).height())) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

You can see code at http://jsfiddle.net/F4FZL/10/ and play with demo at https://jsfiddle.net/F4FZL/10/embedded/result/.

Hope this information will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a really long sidebar on the left side which i wanted to be scrollable at anytime.
For me the solution was even easier than the aforementioned solutions:

```
$('[data-spy="affix"]').on('affix.bs.affix', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
});
```