# Bootstrap affix taller than content, scroll fail

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having the same problem the author of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21691585/bootstrap-3-1-0-affix-too-long) exhibits with affix, specifically the authors comment on the accepted answer. The answerer provides a secondary solution, but this is unsatisfactory.

The issue occurs when all of the following conditions are present:

1. Affixed div is taller than view port
2. Affixed div is tallest part of page
3. User scrolls past affix-top

It is demonstrated in this JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g1ns9k8o/3/ with the following code:

**CSS:**

```
.top-bit { height: 100px; }
.sidebar { width: 200px; padding: 10px; }
.sidebar.affix { top: 10px; }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="top-bit">
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-9">
        <!-- short content -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">
        <div class="sidebar" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
            <!-- long content -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to happen? This just seems like bad design.

Comment: fair question, I'd like precisely the behaviour exhibited here: http://jsfiddle.net/Ja3XT/1/ , but for it not to mess up in the conditions described above. I don't see how it's bad design but I'm all ears.

Comment: The whole point of affix is to keep important content visible and accessible on the viewport at all times. If the element being affixed is larger than the viewport (vertically or horizontally), then this defeats the whole purpose of affixing items. I'm no designer, but if UX is important to you I would post a question about this topic here -> http://ux.stackexchange.com/

Comment: In my opinion, the length of content, or the height of the viewport, should be inconsequential to the functionality of the website.

Comment: To each his own ;) Take a look at Bootstrap's own documentation. Notice how the affixed sidebar expands and collapses as you scroll, in order to avoid your exact problem. http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem and ran into the jerky scroll movement. To fix it, I used JavaScript to compare the height of the affixed element to the element it is sitting next to. If the affixed height is less than the content height, set the affix. Otherwise, just let the affixed element sit where it is.

So, say it's a sidebar that I'm fixing next to a content element.

```
// Pseudocode
if (sidebar.height < content.height) {
    $(sidebar).affix({});
}
```

Comment: probably the only viable solution. it becomes awkward though when the content of either is in anyway dynamic (post page-load).